# How to compute statistics on a list of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of DataFrames all with the same keys and columns. I would like to compute the mean and the std of each element. How can I do it?

EDIT: 
Suppose a list `DFS` of three DataFrames and consider the mean function. The result should be a dataframe `DF_mean` with value in the element `DF_mean[index0, col0] = DFS[0][index0, col0] + DFS[1][index0, col0] + DFS[2][index0, col0] / 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I'd recommend using [pd.Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html) for these kind of stuff.</s> (See the update).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
dfs = {i : pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 5))) for i in range(3)}
pnl = pd.Panel(dfs)
```

Then you can apply descriptive statistics functions on `axis=0`:

```
pnl.std(axis=0)
Out: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  2.886751  2.081666  1.527525  2.516611  0.577350
1  2.081666  3.214550  2.645751  1.154701  2.516611
2  3.214550  4.041452  3.785939  2.645751  4.163332
3  3.511885  2.309401  1.527525  3.785939  0.577350
4  4.509250  4.163332  2.081666  1.732051  2.309401
5  1.000000  3.000000  2.081666  2.645751  3.000000
6  2.000000  1.527525  2.886751  1.527525  2.886751
7  2.645751  2.516611  2.516611  1.732051  0.577350
8  4.509250  0.577350  4.041452  2.081666  1.527525
9  1.527525  3.785939  2.516611  1.000000  1.154701
```

Update:

[pd.Panel will be deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#to-xarray). The most suitable solution in that case is to concat the DataFrames and use MultiIndex. If you pass a dictionary to pd.concat, it will use dictionary keys as the keys argument of the function.

dfs_combined = pd.concat(dfs)

Now, if you take the standard deviation on level 1, the result will be identical:

```
dfs_combined.std(level=1)
Out: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  2.886751  2.081666  1.527525  2.516611  0.577350
1  2.081666  3.214550  2.645751  1.154701  2.516611
2  3.214550  4.041452  3.785939  2.645751  4.163332
3  3.511885  2.309401  1.527525  3.785939  0.577350
4  4.509250  4.163332  2.081666  1.732051  2.309401
5  1.000000  3.000000  2.081666  2.645751  3.000000
6  2.000000  1.527525  2.886751  1.527525  2.886751
7  2.645751  2.516611  2.516611  1.732051  0.577350
8  4.509250  0.577350  4.041452  2.081666  1.527525
9  1.527525  3.785939  2.516611  1.000000  1.154701
```